# Avoid "out of gas" when calling a view function using truffle

Tags: solidity, truffle, ganache

I have a rather computationally expensive `view` function on my smart contract, which works with no problem on `rinkeby` (calling it from etherscan).

However, deploying the contract into a local chain (on ganache) and calling the function from a truffle test file, I get an `out of gas` error. Namely:

> Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: out
> of gas

Here is the code I'm using for the test:

```
const { assert } = require("chai")
require("chai").use(require("chai-as-promised")).should()

const MyContract = artifacts.require("./MyContract.sol");

contract("MyContract", function () {
  let contract
  before(async () => { contract = await MyContract.deployed() })

  describe('main stuffs', () => {
    it('returns SVG', async () => {
      const svg = await contract.getTOKEN(1654673700);
    })
  })
})
```

Is there a way to solve this issue?

I really would like to have a setup where I can test my smart contracts (even computationally expensive ones) without having to deploy to `rinkeby` and manually call the functions.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a truffle-config.js like this, put in a correct amount of gas (see the gas cost on etherscan and then put a little bit more in your truffle-config.js):

```
rinkeby: {
    provider: ...
 
     
    **gas: 3500000,** 
     
    gasPrice: 3000000000,// 3 gwei, kovan.etherscan.io/blocks displays average is 2.5gwei 
    network_id: 4,
  }
```